# Encryption Using Javascript and Python doesn't have the same output

Tags: javascript, python, encryption

Im currently working with encryption for both Python and Javascript. I have currently working with RSA combined with base64 where I have this code for both python and javascript:

Javascript:

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');

const key = new NodeRSA("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCzjsLuAJ18f71jg+ZG/wef3FuFTFK2ZvqBPjM7EwVj1FcLkzfixx6D6u59leFgW4SptOIgBtm9OGW1cCmxYLx1nHkugvoAL9g/vnIz6ejVTcoVYPJwkaGum3qXCPW6Km0canc7/DJtM//Zum40AZls/ZFjJ2YJrEOfevIU77urUwIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

var x = {store_id: 1, url_key: 'hello_world.html', category_id: ''}

const data = key.encrypt(JSON.stringify(x), 'base64')
console.log(data)
```

and Python:

```
import base64
import json

import rsa

pub = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem('''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCzjsLuAJ18f71jg+ZG/wef3FuFTFK2ZvqBPjM7EwVj1FcLkzfixx6D6u59leFgW4SptOIgBtm9OGW1cCmxYLx1nHkugvoAL9g/vnIz6ejVTcoVYPJwkaGum3qXCPW6Km0canc7/DJtM//Zum40AZls/ZFjJ2YJrEOfevIU77urUwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----''')
payload = json.dumps({'store_id': 1, 'url_key': 'hello_world.html', 'category_id': ''},
                     separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')

bs64_encoded = base64.b64encode(rsa.encrypt(payload, pub))
print(bs64_encoded.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output for Javascript:

```
mBXCV95Dpc0sg8gigQWv1WdJNkLU9rlVQTcsFy6ell0PTsDfPh8EAVqFZBL6zM3i3S7P0Z2rSRCJQ6xGQag4yeupZ8yJIttyLk1HNIowhB/nPWqUxAPn59cL2uqP5hMBXSPLYet67DWEzwNkmHA4W2pZc/ysKrTLqUQBYGRYQQ97z3n8kGaGQLgg5afKXHPFne6qEjhiupH6cRKzwj7jwy0fEosBleyDaXWOaNtrK2drGpyR3OFVVq2QtlyXLt1kbYAV01eRSZatgRH0pNXQKEkwqSDmoEz4txDEaP/KU4nwroN/r40cOHYd1/pW2aMqjY0yTM3fm4rWM/nRQAYX5w==
```

Output for Python:

```
OPpU/VMEq7238VQamObgNX8r7pbUnvvNQ/5ie42EpWF3yXT4vNUFxNVaqvMdlNYft6FvVTs5xoAuuhg2JKRk6ar0EvIQL2ZxasIvAIpLhDazJijU5+JQ7u9nEY03QrXbrfHro3620g26LtOw5hAjjUy7pKLKO0hNO+bdobUZrio=
```

and as you can see there is a difference and the output of Javascript is the correct output that im looking for but not python (When using the output, it thorws an invalid data while Javascript response with 200 (correct data)).

My question is that why does it has any difference between Javascript and python when it comes to encryption and how can I make the output of Python to be correct?

Comment: You're encrypting a JSONified string. Is that payload string identical in both languages?

Comment: @jarmod Well according to the code, it should be identical I believe?

Comment: I'm asking if `JSON.stringify(x)` is identical to `json.dumps(...)`. Are you encrypting the same plaintext in both cases?

Comment: @jarmod https://flutterq.com/solved-json-stringify-javascript-and-json-dumps-python-not-equivalent-on-a-list/#:~:text=Solution%201-,The%20difference%20is%20that%20json.,remove%20all%20whitespace%2C%20like%20JSON. Thats what Im doing so it should be same

Comment: If the encrypted results being identical requires the plaintext to have been identical, then you should confirm the latter (by printing them and comparing, or hashing and comparing).

Comment: Right right... I can see that the difference between the json.dumps and JSON.string... https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/gaxoqivoyi.rust - but I dont believe that should do any difference

Comment: Encryption with RSA (with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or OAEP) is not deterministic, i.e. each encryption produces a different ciphertext (even with the same data and key). This is also true for both codes here, as you can easily verify. A correct test is therefore not a comparison of the ciphertexts, but a successful decryption.

Comment: @Topaco Right I see I see, what do you suggest to do in that case for the Python? - Beacuse one thing I can easily see the difference. Is that Python is always has shorter output aswell as JS has always "==" at the end

Comment: Node-RSA seems to use OAEP by default ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa#options)), while the RSA library you use only supports PKCS#1 v1.5 according to the documentation ([here](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa#pure-python-rsa-implementation)). If the Node-RSA code is the reference, you must also use OAEP on the Python side (take a look at [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html#pkcs-1-oaep-rsa) or [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#encryption)).

Comment: Node-RSA uses the default values for OAEP, i.e. SHA1 for the OAEP and the MGF1 digest and an empty label.

Comment: I see I see.. I wonder how taht could be doable in Python, havent figured it out yet

Comment: Have a look at the _Cryptography_ library example linked above (using SHA1 instead of SHA256, of course). The public key can be imported e.g. with [`load_pem_public_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/?highlight=load_pem_public_key#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_pem_public_key).